# Google Analytics Alerts for Campaigns

Tags: google-analytics, google-alerts

Under Acquisition -> Campaigns, we have hundreds of campaigns running. I'd like to be able to create an alert when any of those campaigns have over 100 visits AND an average visitor duration of under 5 seconds on any day.

The reason I need it: We have campaigns, and I'm trying to catch click fraud on those campaigns. If a campaign has a very low average visit duration (0 - 5s) then I want to know that a campaign's visits need to be investigated. For campaigns with number of visits under 100, I don't really care about click fraud, but if a campaign has over 100 visits and average duration is under 5s, then it seems pretty obvious that there is some click fraud happening on the campaign and I want to be alerted about it

When I go to custom alerts, it seems I can only add an alert for a specific campaign with one condition. Anyone know how to add an alert for all campaigns and multiple conditions as described above?

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom segement, under advanced with:

```
Name: Bad Campaign 
Advanced Condiations:
  Campaign does not exactly match (not set)
  AND Visit Duration < 5
```

Then under `Intellegence Events -> Overview -> Custom Alerts -> New Alerts`

```
Alert Name: Bad Campaign
Apply to: 1. WHATEVER
Period: Day
X Send me an email alert

This Applies to: Bad Campaign
Alert me When Vists Is greater than 100
```

Then when the segment reaches 100 visits, you'll get alerted.

Comment: Setting up that segment seems to filter out all visits with duration above 300 (what's 300 by the way? 300 seconds?). I want the segment to be all campaigns with total daily average visit duration under 5s.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the time. I thought you wanted 5 mins.  Which would be: `5min * 60sec/min = 300`.  You'd want to set that just to `Visit Duration < 5` I'll update the answer accordingly.

Comment: If 3 second page load, could someone load any more pages than 1 in 5 seconds? Would bounce be a better metric than visit duration.  Remember all bounce have visit duration of 0, because visit duration on time on page are both based on the next click, and the last page is never timed (unless you wrote js code for on exit events).

Comment: I wasn't clear on what I need it for. We have campaigns, and I'm trying to catch click fraud on those campaigns. If a campaign has a very low average visit duration (0 - 5s) then I want to know that a campaign's visits need to be investigated. For campaigns with number of visits under 100, I don't really care about click fraud, but if a campaign has over 100 visits and average duration is under 5s, then it seems pretty obvious that there is some click fraud happening on the campaign and I want to be alerted about it.

Comment: The above, since it was edited yesterday, should do that for you.